# External entity reference declaration: entities are referenced but not declared (although they are)

Tags: notepad++, entity, dtd, basex

I am trying to reference several entities such as ampersands, hyphens, etc. To do that, I already have a URL where an .ent document is deposited. Unfortunately, I have no DTD document and assuming that there is problem because of that (although all information I need is provided in the ent document).
The URL looks like this:

```
<!-- 
Copyright and Table of Contents (several blocks)
-->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- 
Comment: first block
-->
<!ENTITY xxxx            "xxxx" ><!--comment-->
(...)
<!-- 
Comment: second block
-->
<!ENTITY xxxx            "xxxx" ><!--comment-->
(...)
```

So, the entities are listed in the document. My XML refers to this like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<!DOCTYPE NAME_OF_THE_CREATOR_AND_VERSION [
<!ENTITY % NAME_OF_THE_CREATOR_AND_VERSION.ent SYSTEM "URL"> %NAME_OF_THE_CREATOR_AND_VERSION.ent; ]>
(...)
```

I have added the underlines in order to enhance readability. 

So far, I have

- added standalone="no"
- reduced the reference to `<!DOCTYPE NAME SYSTEM "URL">`
- added the entities in the XML (although I would strongly prefer to find a way to keep an external reference since the .ent document comprises a lot of entities).

  The latter looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE entities [
   <!ENTITY hyphen "&#x02010;">
   <!ENTITY copy "&#x000A9;">
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x000A0;">
   <!ENTITY ndash "&#x02013;">
   <!ENTITY auml "&#x000E4;">
   <!ENTITY uuml "&#x000FC;">
   <!ENTITY deg "&#x000B0;">
   <!ENTITY Delta "&#x00394;">
   <!ENTITY minus "&#x02212;">
   <!ENTITY ensp "&#x02002;">
]>
```

I have checked the XML syntax in BaseX, notepad++ and the XML Validator by w3schools and everytime (except for the internal declaration) it says that the entity (e.g. hyphen) was referenced but not declared or that there is an error in the Markup declaration. Meanwhile, when I checked the ent file it said that there is content added at the end of the document, starting with the entity declarations, or that an invalid element name had been used - but this is probably due to it being an ent file?


Thanks in advance for any help and tipps.

Best,

Eleonore


**EDIT:** I am using the BaseX GUI on Windows 10. I have enabled "Parse DTDs and Entities" as well as the internal XML parser and the chopping of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
<!DOCTYPE root-element-name [
<!ENTITY % myentities SYSTEM
   "myentities.ent">
%myentities;
]>
<root-element-name>&foo; &bar;</root-element-name>
```

As for BaseX, I think its default option disables external entities https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#DTD so you need to set that to `true` to be able to use the external entity e.g. `basex.bat -c "SET DTD true" -i input.xml query.xq`.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried what you suggested but I still get the "hyphen was referenced but not declared" error message. I have set "Parse DTDs and entities" to yes, does this change the external entities to be enabled? Where do I include the "basex.bat..." command you mentioned? Thanks in advance, Eleonore

Comment: `basex.bat` is the command line interface to BaseX you normally use on Windows to run queries from the command line e.g. Powershell or command prompt. It is not clear how you run BaseX and where you have set the options so I can't tell whether your approach should work. Perhaps edit your question and describe in more detail how you use BaseX.

Comment: Thank you, @Martin Honnen, I have added an edit.

Comment: @eleonore.shellstrop, try whether it works *without* using the internal parser, I think that one is not up to the task of supporting advanced DTD features.

Comment: I have tried and, unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I really don't know why.

Comment: @eleonore.shellstrop, can you show us more details of what you are trying to achieve? Are you just using BaseX as an XQuery engine to query XML files on the file system or on the web? Or are you using it as an XML database system? Is the error occuring with XML documents stored in the database? Is the entity file also in the database?

Comment: I am using it as a database system and the error is occuring with similar XML documents in the database. The entity referenced is stored on a website which is then linked in the reference.

Comment: @eleonore.shellstrop, you might want to consider asking on the BaseX mailing list, the BaseX developers are there usually present and responsive and I am sure they can better tell whether such a scenario to have an XML document in the database reference an external entity on a website outside of the database is supported.